# Why is ng-click not working correctly?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code:

```
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="HomeController">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <h1>Hello In APP</h1>
        <button type="button" name="button" ng-click="buyAdFree()">Kaufen</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the button nothing happens. ng-click isn't working like it should. What is my mistake? 
This is my controller:

```
app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.buyAdFree = function() {

    if((window.device && device.platform == "iOS") && window.storekit) {
        storekit.purchase("full_version");
    }

    if((window.device && device.platform == "iOS") && window.storekit) {
        storekit.restore();
    }

    if ((window.device && device.platform == "Android") && typeof inappbilling !== "undefined") {
      inappbilling.init(function(resultInit) {
          inappbilling.getPurchases(function(result) {
              console.log("PURCHASE RESPONSE -> " + JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            function(errorPurchases) {
              console.log("PURCHASE ERROR -> " + errorPurchases);
            });
        },
        function(errorInit) {
          console.log("INITIALIZATION ERROR -> " + errorInit);
        }, {
          showLog: true
        }, ["full_version"]);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Your `buyAdFree` function have 3 if statement, but is really one of them true? if not, your function will return nothing. So for example, if my `device.platform == "windows"`, your function will return nothing

Comment: Thank you, didn't thought about that.